# How can I get the list of columns from a temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I'd like to get the list of columns in a temporary table, similar to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns view.  However, this code:

```
select * 
from   tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where  TABLE_CATALOG = 'tempdb'
and    TABLE_NAME like '#myTemporaryTable%'
```

returns one row per column and per session.  Is it safe to do this:

```
select distinct column_name,data_type 
from   tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where  TABLE_CATALOG = 'tempdb'
and    TABLE_NAME like '#myTemporaryTable%'
```

I have a feeling it isn't, even if you tighten up the like clause so it won't match myTemporaryTable and myTemporaryTable2.

Comment: Could you give the question some context, we may be able to solve the problem further back than having to query tempdb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need query tempdb, I would use object_id

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTemporaryTable')
```